# How do I write a SQL script to find all relationships tied to an original id?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, banking

For example:

I want to pass in a tax id number to find all accounts associated with this tax id. This would simply be:

```sql
SELECT TAX_ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM CUSTOMER_RECORDS
```

I would then have a list of all accounts. However, each account could also have other tax ids associated to it (co-borrower, guarantors, etc). So I want to take the returned accounts and then find all tax ids associated to them. I then need to repeat these steps to find all accounts associated to all of the new tax ids that were returned.

The end result would be a list of accounts and tax ids that all form one "relationship".

I was thinking that a recursive CTE may work for this scenario? However, this is a bit above my skill level in SQL. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Are you actually going infinite with this until you have everything that is possibly associated with the tax id, or just going the 3 layers deep you describe?

Comment: Your question assumes a level of familiarity with your data, but doesn't provide that familiarity. How are "associated" ids defined? Can it be derived from one table, or will it take two, or many? To help us help you, please read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @babno I would like it to return all possible results.

Comment: @EricBrandt There is one table involved and two columns within that table involved. I provided these in my question.

Comment: Ok. Since all the information needed is in the question, we can just sit back and watch the answers roll in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
with customer_records as
(
select 111 tax_id, 0 account_number from dual union
select 1 , 100 from dual union
select 1 , 200 from dual union
select 1 , 300 from dual union
select 1 , 400 from dual union
select 2 , 100 from dual union
select 3 , 202 from dual union
select 4 , 303 from dual union
select 5 , 400 from dual union
select 0 , 222 from dual 
)
SELECT c1.TAX_ID, c1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
FROM CUSTOMER_RECORDS c1
where 1=1
  and c1.tax_id = :tax_id
union
SELECT c2.TAX_ID, c2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
FROM CUSTOMER_RECORDS c1
, CUSTOMER_RECORDS c2
where 1=1
  and c1.tax_id = :tax_id
  and c1.tax_id <> c2.tax_id 
  and c1.account_number = c2.account_number
;
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I was looking for. I will do some testing with the actual data and follow up. Thank you!!

Comment: My pleasure @Oomptz ! Have a nice day!!!  If you don't mind you can upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: @Oomptz - Key thing is "seems to" unless you were kidding about going on with finding the relationship indefinitely. Like you stated in the comments. This answer only gets the first layer.

Comment: @dandarc In my testing this was continuing until it finds all relationships. Did you experience something different?

Comment: Copy the data out of my example into this one - you only get 5 rows with tax_id 1. If you run my answer (edited it - I had missed a spot renaming a field when I first posted), you get 11 rows. 

Because this one here only does 2 steps - first it finds the rows that match the tax ID given. Then it finds the rows that match the account number from that first step. Then it stops. You said in the comments to the question it should repeat that over and over until it finds the whole relationship.

Does your real data stop at 1 step like this? If it doesn't, this approach is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do this with a [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). Use caution - these things can get away from you if you are not careful and then you get a call from a DBA "why is query running for 6 days". Example:

```
with base_data as
(
  select 1 as tax_id, 'A' as account_number from dual union all
  select 1 as tax_id, 'B' as account_number from dual union all
  select 2 as tax_id, 'A' as account_number from dual union all
  select 2 as tax_id, 'B' as account_number from dual union all
  select 2 as tax_id, 'C' as account_number from dual union all
  select 3 as tax_id, 'D' as account_number from dual union all
  select 3 as tax_id, 'E' as account_number from dual union all
  select 4 as tax_id, 'E' as account_number from dual union all
  select 4 as tax_id, 'F' as account_number from dual union all
  select 5 as tax_id, 'A' as account_number from dual union all
  select 5 as tax_id, 'F' as account_number from dual union all
  select 6 as tax_id, 'G' as account_number from dual union all
  select 7 as tax_id, 'H' as account_number from dual union all
  select 7 as tax_id, 'I' as account_number from dual union all
  select 8 as tax_id, 'I' as account_number from dual union all
  select 8 as tax_id, 'K' as account_number from dual
)

select distinct bd.*
from base_data bd
start with tax_id = :taxID
connect by nocycle (prior account_number = account_number or prior tax_id = tax_id)
--and level <= 10
order by 1, 2
```

As written, with "and level <= 10" commented out, this will return all items. May want to uncomment it and set a maximum level - essentially puts a limit on how far down the rabit hole the query will look.